Can the price of the stock rise even when there are still sellers asking for a lower price?
I want to know can the price of the stock rise even when there are still sellers asking for a lower price?
For example, the listed price is $0.05. The asking price is $0.055. There are 10 orders shown for that asking price. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but those 10 orders can be conceived as a line in which first come first serve. The volume of these orders is unknown, but hypothetically the sum total of these ten orders amounts to 100,000 in volume. When the stock price reaches $0.055 the first in line will have their order filled, and so on and so forth (each order is 10,000 in volume). However, 3 orders were not completed.
So in this situation, can or does the stock price rise even though these three orders are incomplete? If Yes then could I get to the first in line for a higher price like $0.06?
I'm fairly new to this, but I'm starting to realise the importance of volume. My concern is that there has been a very large volume at a lower price, and through the use of a limit order there is a monopoly on a certain price. Let's say there is one order asking to sell 100,000 at $0.055 with a specified limit order for the next three months. Following the rule of first come first serve, they have taken over that position. No one is going to get their order in until that one order is filled.

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what the stock price is: it’s very simply the price at which the last sale was done, I.e. when bid and ask met. It’s not a separate number, it’s just the price a buyer and a seller agreed on.

Related: Can someone explain a stock's "bid" vs. "ask" price relative to "current" price?

@jcaron Arguably, there's no single ‘stock price’.  There are many different prices: those of the latest on-exchange trade, the best bid and offer in the order book and their midpoint, ditto in the quote book, off-book and off-exchange trades, uncrossing trades at the end of an open/close/other auction, or even in a few cases set by an official committee. Data providers must synthesise a headline price from all that data (and they don't always do so in exactly the same way, especially for stocks which are very slow/low-volume/suspended, or while the market's closed).

Lower prices take precedence over higher prices regardless of when the orders were placed. For orders with the same, the first in line usually wins...
The exception is if the front order is "all or none" and there's not enough demand to satisfy the full order, then another order with a higher price (or a smaller order at the same price) could be use to fill the order.
So no, there's not a way for one large order to "monopolize" the order book. Someone with a lower price or a smaller volume could come in and take precedence.

Is that really true? If I sell some shares and someone wants to buy them for $10 and someone else for $12, the exchange will always match me with the $10 buyer?

"For order with the same, the first in line usually wins..."
I'm going to give more context from a real life stock.
My reasoning is as follows: a stock has had the same number of asks of 0.025 over a period of a few days, therefore, it seems reasonable to conclude that these are 21 limit orders of 0.025 set to a maximum of three months. So, in this case isn't there the risk of a "monopoly" by anyone in line?
I should have mentioned that the number of asks hasn't changed.
These aren't a FOK/AON type order since the same number of asks is repeating over a few days right?

Thanks for the response by the way

@DJClayworth OP was asking from the buying side - from the selling side, the higher price would take precedence.

@LiamO'Reilly unless there are lower asks, the 0.025 asks will get filled until they run out. If they're willing to sell for less than anyone else, then they will get the priority.

You have the essence of it correct, for the very specific scenario you paint. Yes, you could "get in line" with a limit order for $0.06 and hope that buyers eventually exhaust all of the $0.055 offers available.
However, there is nothing to stop other sellers from coming along and offering their shares at the same current ask price (or even lower - putting them "ahead of the line" in terms of favorable offers to buyers.)
In addition, we don't know if the existing 100,000 units offered have an expiration date on the order, whether any of them are "fill or kill", and we don't know from the buyer side which orders are "all or cancel". So there are a bunch of variables (examples given here are not exhaustive) that can result in some of the orders not getting filled in the same order they showed up on the order book.

Thanks for the response. The hypothetical scenario is based on a real life stock. The stock has had the same asking price for a few days of 0.025, so I reason that there must be 21 limit orders of 0.025, which is different from what you suggest.
You're still making a valid point. Once you mentioned that, I realised I need to add more context. Like I said, I'm still new to this, so I'm not totally familiar with all of the types of orders that can be placed. I'm using TD Canada Trust web broker basic, it doesn't show FOK or AON type orders.

When it comes down to it, it's timing, price match and limit rules.
Who got the order in first, best price then any other limits.
The share will only go up if the market closes and the last trade was higher than the close of the prior day. You can put a trade on to buy at 6 cents so it is best price and will likely immediately fill but  the next trade will be less and it will not move the share price up except for the nano second it takes to fill your trade and the next one to happen.
Unless you are willing to spend some serious money (Bloomberg $20k+/month system) or way less expensive, pay in person brokerage rates you won't get parcel level data. You will never know who is in front of you.
Some further thoughts.
It sounds like you are looking to trade i.e. buy/sell as quickly as possible to make money. As opposed to invest where you do some analysis buy a stock and hold it for a year or so (usually getting long term tax benefits).
I have historically done trading of this type using a limit order at 5 cents to buy and limit order to sell at 5.5 cents can make you some small returns (10% - brokerage - tax).
There are a few things that need consideration namely volume, automation and hype.
If you're trading a company where the price is this small there may not be sufficient turnover (volume). There may be some passionate owners holding 80% of the company and not buying or selling. If the 'volume' is in the millions you should consider what that is in dollars? It could take days or weeks to fill the order if the volume is low.
Automated trading is quite advanced and there are a number of funds that work at these price levels buying and selling millions of shares before you even get your order on. looking at daily volume for the last few days might give you the answer if automated trading is happening, you'll see a ton of movement with the price not moving much.
Lastly there is hype. It might be a low level stock now but if it is 'found' buying it at 6 or even more cents might be the buy of the century but it is unlikely. Do some very limited research. How much cash on hand is there? Selling stock to raise money is common and will diminish the value of the shares.
